# TimeZone Date Formatting Issue

Tags: swift, date, timezone, dateformatter

I'm trying to get a date from a string with multiple time zones, It works without any problems if the API returns zones with abbreviations like `CST` or `UTC` but it fails if it returns `EET`

```
let timeString = "17:32 (EET)"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm (zzz)"
let time = formatter.date(from: timeString) // return nil
```

Any idea what is the issue might be?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because there is more than one timezone that matches the timezone abbreviation or the date formatter's default date (January 1st) doesn't match the daylight savings of the timezone abbreviation used. Not all countries uses daylight savings time as well it might change at any time. Check this [link](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/eet). This will probably happen for all non US timezones abbreviation as well. For example `CST` it is used for `"China Standard Time"` and `"Chicago Standard Time"` as well. You can workaround that issue setting your date formatter property `isLenient` to true. Note that this will result in a date of January 1st 2000 with a probably incorrect timezone offset. If you have control of your string input you should use the timezone identifiers instead of its abbreviations to avoid ambiguity. You should also set your date formatter's locale to `"en_US_POSIX"` when parsing fixed date format to avoid date formatter's reflecting the users device locale and settings:

```
let timeString = "17:32 (EET)"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm (zzz)"
formatter.isLenient = true
let date = formatter.date(from: timeString) // "Jan 1, 2000 at 1:32 PM" "BRT Brazilian Standard Time"
```

So you should use `"GMT+2"` or `"GMT-3"` to avoid ambiguity or as I have already suggested use its identifiers `"HH:mm (VV)"` i.e. `"Europe/Athens"` or `"America/Sao_Paulo"`

Comment: Thanks Leo, your answer is very clear. I think the issue I have is more related to the API as the response is different depending on the time zone of the user. So, i was trying to find a solution that works with any time zone without need of fixing the Local of the user time zone. 

I will check the availability of sending the time zone of the user in the response if this might help, or if you have any suggestions regarding this point. Thanks again!

Comment: @AhmedM.Hassan You are welcome. As you can see in the link I posted the date formatter does not have enough information to infer the correct timezone as it depends on the country daylight savings time. There is multiple scenarios so the result would be unpredictable. That's why it returns nil. You might set the date formatter's defaultDate as well and a calendar as well to help it parse your date.

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks again 